# Odd spacing between TikZ node and minipage. How to counteract?

Tags: minipage, tikz-node

As shown in the example, there is additional space between a Ti*k*Z node/object and a minipage containing only one line of text. How to counteract this? I'm probably overlooking something very basic.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[papersize={5.5in,8.5in},margin=0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\parindent0pt

\begin{document}

\noindent
\tikz{\node[draw]{This is some text};}%
\par
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
One line. Why extra space after node with one-line minipage?
\end{minipage}
\par

\bigskip

\noindent
\tikz{\node[draw]{This is some text};}%
\par
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
One line. And some more text to see just what is happening here if at all possible. One line. And some more text to see just what is happening here if at all possible.
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: TikZ/minipage spacing]

Comment: Use `\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}` in the second minipage so it aligns the baseline of the top line in the minipage with the baseline of the surrounding text

Comment: Text is normally spaced `\baselineskip` between baselines, while boxes (whose baselines are too far apart) are normally spaced `\lineskip` between the bottom of one box and the top of the next.

Comment: @SimonDispa Ah. I was afraid I was overlooking something basic, and so I was. Thanks.